# Display joystick input on the screen?

Tags: windows-7, game-controller

I'm trying to record myself playing a game with a joystick (specifically, a Gamecube controller) and was looking for software that displayed my input on the screen.

It would be even better if it hooked into DirectX games like the program Fraps does, but that might be a little bit out there.

Does software that does this exist?

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've come to this is scripting [glovepie's fakecursors.](http://www.glovepie.org/w/index.php?title=Preliminary_Documentation_v0.43#Fake_Cursors)

> In addition to the real mouse cursor, GlovePIE can show multiple fake cursors. These fake cursors look and behave just like the real cursor, and can do most of the same things.

I was about to develop a glovepie script when I decided to search for something already completed and only came across this question.
GlovePIE is an input emulator with its own scripting language.

The following script will display text in the top left corner of the screen in teal.

```
Cursor6.Caption="stuff"
```

Its also possible use custom images for the cursor graphic

```
Cursor2.Image
Cursor1.image = "c:\data\mycursor.cur"
```

[glovepie download](http://glovepie.org/glovepie_download.php)

update:
Test script using Cursor.Caption text:

```
if joy.Button1 then var.A = "A" else var.A = " "

Cursor6.PosX = 40
Cursor6.PosY = 10
Cursor6.Caption = "TEST: " + var.A
```

Test script using Cursor.Image:

```
Cursor1.PosX = 400
Cursor1.PosY = 400
Cursor1.Caption = ""
Cursor1.Image = "A.cur"
Cursor1.Visible = joy.Button1
```

"A.cur" was created using Paint.NET. When testing this overlay on a game I noticed a black rectangle when the graphic disappeared or changed, which may make this solution unacceptable.

Comment: Nice first post